# Ionic 4 cordova android debugging in vs code breakpoints not verified

Tags: cordova, debugging, ionic-framework, vscode-debugger

It’s not possible for me, to debug in Vs Code anymore.
I can attach to the emulator, but the breakpoints are all unveryfied. I have the same behaviour in Windows 10 and in Ubuntu 18.04.
With Ionic 3 I hadn’t these problems.

I found out, that ionic 4 doesn`t use app scripts anymore. So the sourcemap files are not in the .sourcemaps folder in the root now, but in the www folder.

I tried

```
“cwd”: “${workspaceFolder}/src”
```

or

```
“cwd”: “{workspaceFolder}/www"
```

in

```
{
    "name": "Attach to running android on emulator",
    "type": "cordova", "request": "attach", "platform": "android",
    "target": "emulator", "port": 9222, "sourceMaps": true, "cwd": "{workspaceFolder}”
    },
```

but that didn`t work, either.

**Some Informations about the system:**

```
Ionic version:
Ionic:

Ionic CLI : 5.2.6 (C:\Users*****\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.16.3\node_modules\ionic)
Ionic Framework : @ionic/angular 4.8.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
@angular-devkit/schematics : 8.1.3
@angular/cli : 8.1.3
@ionic/angular-toolkit : 2.0.0

Cordova:

Cordova CLI : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0
Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 4 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.6.0
native-run : 0.2.8

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users*****\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
NodeJS : v10.16.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm : 6.9.0
OS : Windows 10

Steps to reproduce:
ionic start myApp tabs
Start emulator
ionic cordova run android
Start debugging

My launch.json

{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
“version”: “0.2.0”,
“configurations”: [
{
“name”: “Run Android on device”,
“type”: “cordova”,
“request”: “launch”,
“platform”: “android”,
“target”: “device”,
“port”: 9222,
“sourceMaps”: true,
“cwd”: “{workspaceFolder}", "ionicLiveReload": false }, { "name": "Run iOS on device", "type": "cordova", "request": "launch", "platform": "ios", "target": "device", "port": 9220, "sourceMaps": true, "cwd": "{workspaceFolder}”,
“ionicLiveReload”: false
},
{
“name”: “Attach to running android on device”,
“type”: “cordova”,
“request”: “attach”,
“platform”: “android”,
“target”: “device”,
“port”: 9222,
“sourceMaps”: true,
“cwd”: “{workspaceFolder}" }, { "name": "Attach to running iOS on device", "type": "cordova", "request": "attach", "platform": "ios", "target": "device", "port": 9220, "sourceMaps": true, "cwd": "{workspaceFolder}”
},
{
“name”: “Run Android on emulator”,
“type”: “cordova”,
“request”: “launch”,
“platform”: “android”,
“target”: “emulator”,
“port”: 9222,
“sourceMaps”: true,
“cwd”: “{workspaceFolder}", "ionicLiveReload": false }, { "name": "Attach to running android on emulator", "type": "cordova", "request": "attach", "platform": "android", "target": "emulator", "port": 9222, "sourceMaps": true, "cwd": "{workspaceFolder}/src”
},
{
“name”: “Serve to the browser (ionic serve)”,
“type”: “cordova”,
“request”: “launch”,
“platform”: “serve”,
“cwd”: “{workspaceFolder}", "devServerAddress": "localhost", "sourceMaps": true, "ionicLiveReload": true }, { "name": "Simulate Android in browser", "type": "cordova", "request": "launch", "platform": "android", "target": "chrome", "simulatePort": 8000, "livereload": true, "sourceMaps": true, "cwd": "{workspaceFolder}”
},
{
“name”: “Simulate iOS in browser”,
“type”: “cordova”,
“request”: “launch”,
“platform”: “ios”,
“target”: “chrome”,
“simulatePort”: 8000,
“livereload”: true,
“sourceMaps”: true,
“cwd”: “{workspaceFolder}" }, { "name": "Run Browser", "type": "cordova", "request": "launch", "platform": "browser", "target": "chrome", "simulatePort": 8000, "livereload": true, "sourceMaps": true, "cwd": "{workspaceFolder}”
}
]
}

Vs Code Version:
1.37.1

Cordova Tools Version:
1.8.5
```

Can somebody help me here please? What can I do to male the breakpoints verified?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I debugged project via "Run Android on emulator" and I had the error 'Error processing "breakpointLocations": Error: 'Debugger.getPossibleBreakpoints' wasn't found     at Client.processMessage'. I downgraded VS code version from 1.46 to 1.37 and it fixed